# It is safe to keep jdbc connection open for a long

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm using Java database connectivity for my projects.

Everything is good but there is a problem for each statement I make a new connection and execute a statement.

Obviously this is very bad for lots of requests like 5000 per minute.

Is it safe to keep the Java database connectivity connection for a long like keep it for 1 minute.

Comment: What kind of connection pool are you using?

Comment: No it isn't safe. The server will time-out idle connections. Use a connection pool.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Speaking about relational databases: Yes, that is good.

Opening a database connection is a fairly expensive operation.

That's why you use a connection pool in such cases.

Comment: Your answer is self-contradictory. To use a pool you have to close the connection to get it back into the pool.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne No. What you think of as closing the connection does not really close it. Rather, the connection is kept open, but returned to the pool. That is the operational principle behind a connection pool.